# How to connect nodejs backend to a frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, web-applications

I've a problem. I've created a simple CRUD app with nodeJs. The app uses a mysql db, and can do the Create, Insert, Delete and Read operations. For example a read operation:

```
app.get('/run',(req,res) => {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM run', (err,rows,fields) =>{
        if(!err)
        res.send(rows)
        else
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

As you can see, I have used express. I'm using nodeJs for the first time, so I'm very inexpert. I want that when the application is acceded at the "/homepage" route, the homepage.html is rendered. I've succeeded to do that. But when I render the HTML page, I want for example that on the click event to the submit button into the page, an alert is opened. Then I want to redirect the user to another HTML page (so I want to redirect the user from the homepage to another route defined by me).

```
app.get('/prova', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "homepage.html"));
  });
```

To be honest, the HTML page returned is "static" it doesn't seem to see the click event that I defined in the HTML file. In other word, I don't understand how to connect the Node JS backend to the JavaScript fronted. This is the first time that I use this language, so many concepts are not clear to me. Can you help me, please? Thank you so much!

Comment: Node.js server is similar to other web servers, use AJAX or submit a form to run the server-side code.

Comment: i suggest axios to send Ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can make your webpage dynamic with some template engines like ejs, pug, jade, handlebars. For that you need to specify which template engine you are going to use in you main app.js (or server.js) file, like below:

```
// setting template engine
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // in this case pug
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // this is the folder where you keep html for rendering

// static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // this folder will be available for client side, for e.g. css, js, images are stored
```

And then

```
app.get('/prova', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "homepage.html"));
});
```

change to

```
app.get('/prova', function (req, res) {
  res.send(data).render('main_page');
});
```

main_page is html like file (in my case main_page.pug) which is going to render data dynamically. To consume data in client side check out docs [pug-documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)